# Swift 4: Variable 'value' inferred to have type 'Void', which may be unexpected?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to save the download URL, for images stored in firebase storage, in the DB. I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398842/constant-result-inferred-to-have-type-which-may-be-unexpected), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51974047/how-to-store-images-in-firebase-storage-and-save-link-to-them-on-database?newreg=9d7c359852dc4d38ac90c04e36d92ead#), however I am getting the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Void' to type '[String : String]' in coercion

This happens on the line indicated bellow:

```
storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
    guard let downloadURL = url else {
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
        return
    }
    //database integration
let ref = Database.database().reference()
let usersRef = ref.child("usersPosts")

let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
let newUserRef = usersRef.child(uid!).child("post\(takePicViewController().finalPost + PhotoArray.sharedInstance.numberPost)")

PhotoArray().dowloadImgUrls.append(("\(downloadURL)"))
let downloadUrlArray = PhotoArray().dowloadImgUrls
var value = newUserRef.setValue(["Image\(self.number)": "\(downloadUrlArray)"])// WARNING IS HERE

addImageURLToDatabase(uid: uid!, values: value as [String : String]) // ERROR IS HERE
```

And on this line which I will put bellow for reference (although its also indicated above) is getting a warning, also found bellow.

```
var value = newUserRef.setValue(["Image\(self.number)": "\(downloadUrlArray)"])
```

> Variable 'value' inferred to have type 'Void', which may be unexpected

Edit: I forgot to include the function being called:

```
    func addImageURLToDatabase(uid:String, values:[String:String]) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let usersReference = ref.child("usersPosts").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!)

    usersReference.updateChildValues(values) { (error, ref) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error)
            return
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the function `newUserRef.setValue(...)` does not return anything. Change your code to this:

```
let value = ["Image\(self.number)": "\(downloadUrlArray)"]
newUserRef.setValue(value)
addImageURLToDatabase(uid: uid!, values: value)
```

Comment: I was able to get rid of the errors however when I ran the code I saw this in the database: Image0: "", I was going to try and do somthing allong the lines of, let value = ["Image\(self.number)": "\(downloadUrlArray[takePicViewController().numberPost])"] but I get an error saying I cannot subscript String with an Int. Am I doing this right? if so how do i fix this. And if not what should i change?

Comment: What type is the `downloadUrlArray` variable? Can you hold Option and click on the variable's name?

Comment: var dowloadImgUrls = [String]()  I ran it but this time it just crashed after sending data, not exactly when I pressed but after some seconds (20). And the database did not get any new values added.

Comment: Please open a new question with the new code and state what issues you are having and the line that crashed.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `newUserRef.setValue` does not return a value, it just stores it.

It appears that this is what you want instead:

```
var value = ["Image\(self.number)": "\(downloadUrlArray)"]
newUserRef.setValue(value)

addImageURLToDatabase(uid: uid!, values: value as [String : String])
```